# HTML tags aren't matching for me when using Regular Expressions on PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to get HTML tags from the code but it only gives the string between the opening and closing HTML tags.

```
<?
$string = 'this is <em>first</em> test';

preg_match('/<.+?>/', $string, $matches);

echo '<pre>';
    print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

This code should give me **`<em>`first`</em>`** but instead I only get **first** from the array

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The best way to do it is by not using a RegExp. See [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: `.` is any non new line character, `+` is one or more of the previous character/group, `?` stops the matching at the first instance of the next character. e.g. `<` everything until the first `>` ... `em` if you had grouped the `.+?` you would have gotten the `em` in the first capture group. Group 0 is everything matched. Go with the parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for the following pattern:

```
<[^<>]+?>[^<>]*?<\/[^<>]+?>
```

This works only for non-nested HTML (e.g. `this is <em>first</em> test`), but not for nested. You should definitively look for an HTML parser and not do this by yourself - as already mentioned in the comments.

Here is a runnable example:

```js
var text = 'this is <em>first</em> test';
var match = text.match(/<[^<>]+?>[^<>]*?<\/[^<>]+?>/g);
console.log(match);
```